# is there possible to define different version for different device in flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios, flutter-windows

Hey everyone is there possible to define multi version for flutter application for different devices, for example build an application with version of 1.1.1 for android devices and version of 1.3.1 for desktop applications?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link : https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b

or try `flutter_flavors`

This way you can manage multiple build numbers or version number for apps based on native configuration.